# Pass data from component in router-outlet to a "Parent'' component [Angular 2]

Tags: typescript, angular

I would like to know how I can pass data from a component displayed in a router-outlet tag located in a "parent" component HTML template to this parent component?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a parent Component at the top. And in that parent component you need to inject a service where you need it.

service should be like:

```
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class HeaderService {
 private headerSource: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
 header = this.headerSource.asObservable();

 changeMode(mode) {
     this.headerSource.next(mode);
 }
}
```

and in your parent component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { HeaderService } from "../HeaderService";
@Component({
  selector: "App",
  template: `<navbar *ngIf="userMode"></navbar>
         <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        `
})

export class AppComponent  {
   userMode: boolean = false;
   subscription: Subscription;


 constructor(private headerService: HeaderService) { 
   this.subscription = this.headerService.header
        .subscribe(mode => this.userMode = mode);

 } 
}
```

now you can change mode from child component inside router-outlet like this:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderService } from "../HeaderService";

 @Component({
    selector: "child",
    templateUrl: "app/components/home.html"
 })
 export class HomeComponent{
   constructor(private headerService: HeaderService) {
      this.headerService.changeMode(true);
   })
 }
```

Hope so this may help in your case. Gud Luck!